# How to filter shuttle list for a given word in Oracle Apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a shuttle list in Oracle Apex with list of over 500 values so it's very difficult to get the required value so I want to keep a search bar above the shuttle list and search a word that returns contained text (from search bar) in the shuttle list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this plugin:

https://apex.world/ords/f?p=100:710:12202826165752::::P710_PLG_ID:NL.DETORA.APEX.RESTRICT_SHUTTLE_VAUES

If you have questions about how to set it up, do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Hi , Thanks very much for the plugin, it's really good and worked exactly the way I need.

Comment: Hi.. Is there anyway to make the search a bit quicker? The search is currently taking over 30 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how:

- create a text item, let's name it `:P1_SEARCH`
- set "Submit when enter pressed" property to "Yes"
- modify shuttle item's query by adding a `WHERE` clause (or additional condition, if it already exists) as

  ```
  where some_column like '%' || :P1_SEARCH ||'%'
  ```

[EDIT]

If submitting the page fires validations (which you don't have to happen at the moment), then

- set "Submit when enter pressed" back to "No"
- go to shuttle item's properties
- set  "Cascading LOV Parent Item(s)" to `P1_SEARCH`

Comment: Hi.. @littlefoot   Thanks for response.. There's a problem with this. the search works when enter pressed but that enter triggers to create the record in form and triggers all other validations where the values have not been entered yet under the shuttle list will throw errors..

Comment: You're welcome. I've edited my message; have a look, please.

Comment: This works great.  What is the best way to show the entire selection in Shuttle when the search block has no text selected.  Ideally, it would show all the records when no search criteria is typed or when the page is first loaded.

Comment: Any suggestions to the comment above?  When I default the search to a %, it does what I want, but the search variable does not seem to be blank or null so adding a clause OR P1_SEARCH is null does not seem to work.